# How to print all the eigen values using np.linalg.eigh(A)?

Tags: python, numpy

I have symmetric matrix of size 2200 * 2200. 
I use the following command in numpy to diagonalize  :

```
np.linalg.eigh(A)
```

It gives output as follows:

```
(array([ -1.93221186e-14,  -1.53743240e-14,  -3.58303176e-15, ...,
     4.95098104e+01,   5.06117042e+01,   5.07858517e+01]).
```

Please suggest me a way , so that it can print all the 2200 eigen values. 
Thanks for your reply in advance

Answer (score 3):

Just use tuple unpacking:

`eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eigh(A)`

Then you will have a 1-d array `eigenvalues` with `len(eigenvalues) == 2200`.  You can iterate and print that as usual if you like.

```
for eigenvalue in eigenvalues:
    print(eigenvalue)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply, it works. Just a naive question, if we use for loop will it no take more time as you increase the size? can we do it more effectively. ( i do not have much knowledge of programming)

Comment: Yes, it will take more time and there's not really any way of getting around that it's `O(N)`.  You could print `'\n'.join([str(x) for x in eigenvalues])` but it's still a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested before, you could use tuple unpacking to store your eigenvalues in a separate array. Then you could use the `np.savetxt` routine to write out your array:

```
import sys
import numpy as np

eigvals, eigvecs = np.linalg.eigh(A)
np.savetxt(sys.stdout, eigvals, delimiter=" ", fmt="%15.8E")
```

Nice thing here is, if you decide to write your arrays into a file instead to the screen, you can use a file handler (or even a file name) instead of sys.stdout.

Comment: You're welcome. :-) You could time whether it is faster or not as the one proposed by wim. Then, maybe in 1 or 2 days, you could consider to accept one of the answers here as the final answer, as they both give a correctly working solution to the specified problem.